# Merge all workbooks except the Workbook which has the codes

Tags: excel, vba, loops, while-loop

What could be wrong in below code I am using. I have tried "And" and "Or" keywords as well in order to skip the Macro WB which has the codes, but VBA keeps merging the code file as well along with the rest. Any suggestion.

[image: All_Buttons Sheet]

```
Sub Merge_All_FileName_WB()
Dim MyWB As Workbook
Dim Filename As String
Dim Sheet As Worksheet
Dim Path As String

Dim T1, T2, T3, T4, T5 As Range

Set T1 = Sheets("All_Buttons").Range("B1")
Set T2 = Sheets("All_Buttons").Range("B2")
Set T3 = Sheets("All_Buttons").Range("B3")
Set T4 = Sheets("All_Buttons").Range("B4")

If T1.Value = "This Workbook Path" Then
Path = Application.ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator
End If

If T1.Value = "Choose New Path" Then
Path = Application.InputBox("Enter New Path", Default:=Replace(Application.DefaultFilePath, "Documents", ""))
End If

If T2.Value = "" And T3.Value = "" Then
Filename = Dir(Path & "*" & T4)
End If

If T2.Value <> "" And T3.Value = "" Then
Filename = Dir(Path & T2 & "*" & "*" & T4)
End If

If T2.Value <> "" And T3.Value <> "" Then
MsgBox ("Choose one Between Cell A2 & A3")
End If
    

If T2.Value = "" And T3.Value = "" And T4.Value = "All_Excel_Files" Then

Filename = Dir(Path & "*.*")
End If

If T2.Value <> "" And T3.Value = "" And T4.Value = "All_Excel_Files" Then
Filename = Dir(Path & T2 & "*" & "*.")
End If

Do While Filename <> "" 'And Filename <> Application.ThisWorkbook.Name

If Filename <> Application.ThisWorkbook.Name Then
Set MyWB = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True, UpdateLinks:=False)
For Each Sheet In Sheet.Sheets
If ActiveSheet.FilterMode = True Then
ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
End If
Sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Next Sheet
Workbooks(Filename).Close

End If
Filename = Dir()


Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Most likely it is the `activeworkbook` that is causing this problem. Why not reference the workbook being opened to an object like  `Set mywbk = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True, UpdateLinks:=False)`

Comment: Hi Charile Tried what you suggested as well but ended up getting the same result.

Comment: Just noticed. Try replacing every `activesheet` with `sheet` inside your `For` block .

Comment: Hi Charlie Code is added now. This code works fine. If path is same or have to choose different path. Can pick different extension of excel one by one. Can Choose file start name. But it compile itself whenever I try to copy each excel file within the same folder and copies sheet within the file too.

Comment: `For Each Sheet In Sheet.Sheets` should be `For Each Sheet In MyWB.Sheets` and also replace `activesheet` with `sheet` inside your `For` block